# how to match pg_repack binary and db version

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgresql-extensions

I am using this command  `sudo apt-get install postgresql-11-repack` to install pg_repack(default to 1.4.8).

```
postgresql-11-repack is already the newest version (1.4.8-1.pgdg20.04+1).
```

when i run "create extension pg_repack" in rds postgres 11, it creates by default with version 1.4.4.

```
                                        List of installed extensions
     Name     | Version |   Schema   |                         Description
--------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_repack    | 1.4.4   | public     | Reorganize tables in PostgreSQL databases with minimal locks
```

so pg_repack fails due to mismatch in version number between ec2 and db.

```
ERROR: pg_repack failed with error: program 'pg_repack 1.4.8' does not match database library 'pg_repack 1.4.4'
```

1. how do i create repack extension with version 1.4.8 in DB?
2. if above is not possible, how do i downgrade by pg_repack version on ec2 back to 1.4.4 same as my db.
3. AWS does not allow me to add this extension under "shared_preload_libraries" either.

Error compiling from source:

```
    gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer pg_repack.o pgut/pgut.o pgut/pgut-fe.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,--as-needed  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpq -L/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib -lpgcommon -lpgport -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lrt -lcrypt -ldl -lm -o pg_repack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpgcommon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpgport
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:430: pg_repack] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/pg_repack-ver_1.4.4/bin'
make: *** [Makefile:35: all] Error 2
enter code here
```

Comment: repack is not a shared preload library. Just find version `1.4.4`  binary [somewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package) or compile it from [pg_repack version 1.4.4 source code](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/releases/tag/ver_1.4.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your inputs. Here are the steps i followed to setup pg_repack 1.4.7 in EC2 & RDS Postgres

```
wget https://api.pgxn.org/dist/pg_repack/1.4.7/pg_repack-1.4.7.zip

sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
--remove pg 15 from installation ( At present, PG 14 and the latest PG 15 version are not supported, and an error will be reported during installation: pointer type error ) 

sudo make
sudo make install
sudo cp bin/pg_repack /usr/local/bin/
```

[image]

```
create extension pg_repack; -- RDS Postgres
```

Answer (score 6):

### **First**, check to see if the package version exists for the current distro version:

```
apt list -a postgresql-11-repack
```

the type of output will look something like this:

> postgresql-11-repack/buster-pgdg 1.4.4-2.pgdg110+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.3-1.pgdg110+1] 
> postgresql-11-repack/now 1.4.3-1.pgdg110+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.4.4-2.pgdg110+1]

**If the package version you need is listed, you can then remove the existing package and install the specific version needed by removing the existing package and installing the targeted version as shown below** ([here](https://serverfault.com/a/604549/994945) is a good reference on why the debian package for the pg_repack extension version `1.4.4` is numbered `1.4.4-1` or `1.4.4-2` and so on)

this is a bit contrived, but in this example I removed `1.4.3` and installed `1.4.4` (the same procedure would apply if you had `1.4.8-1` debian package already installed and you wanted to install `1.4.4-2` specifically):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-11-repack

sudo apt-get install postgresql-11-repack=1.4.4-2
```

**If the package does not show up, you can alternatively build it from source:**

```
git clone https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack.git
cd pg_repack/
git checkout tags/ver_1.4.4
make
make install
```

*One reason you might want to build from source is because the version of the package you need is from a previous version of the OS and you do not want to deal with that type of joy specifically ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60557/549100))*

Comment: when i ran this "sudo apt-get install postgresql-11-repack=1.4.4-2" --> It complains on the version number 1.4.4-2. Can you advise how do you come up with "-2" at the end?

Comment: building from source leads to the error. Edited the description with error

Comment: the `apt list -a postgresql-11-repack` will show you the version numbers for the package

Comment: thanks. in my case apt list shows version number - 1.4.8-1

Comment: @Falcon awesome, did it solve your issue?

Comment: it was definitely helpful. In my case, i specifically want to use pg_repack in both db and ec2 and the version i choose is 1.4.7